# The network connection was lost.NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, afnetworking

Could anyone help on this?.I am using AFNetworking(1.x) POST method in my app.But frequently i am getting:

> 'The network connection was lost' error.Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 “The network connection was lost.”

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
op.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [self SuccessResponse:responseObject:reqType];
    NSLog(@"JSON responseObject: %@ ",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715724/code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have working internet connection.

Try to use below code.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];

NSDictionary *params ; // Pass your POST Parameters here by creating the Dictionary.

[manager POST:@"your api here" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,  id responseObject) {
          // Success 
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // Request failed
        // To get failed response data use operation.responseObject
        NSLog(@"like request failed %@", error);
}];
```

Hope this will help you.